# Error parsing snippet xml: unexpected and of data in file

Tags: xml, sublimetext3, c99

I want to save the created snippet but I get:

> Error parsing snippet xml: unexpected and of data in file Packages/User/c99/hello.sublime-snippet on line: 9

Answer (score 0):

This error message is telling you that the snippet that you created is broken. Since snippets are XML, the most likely culprit is that the XML of the snippet is invalid, which could be due to anything from a missing or un-closed tag to generally malformed XML.

Your question doesn't include the content of the file that's broken, so we're unable to help with what the underlying problem might be.

The second part of your error message tells you the file that is broken and the location in the file that's invalid, so in order to fix it you need to open the snippet back up again and then double check that everything is valid.

You can use `View Package File` from the command palette to open up the file named in the error message (`Packages/User/c99/hello.sublime-snippet`); once you choose the command enter parts of the name to filter the list of package files down to make it easier to find in the list.

The error is being noticed on line 9, which could mean that that line is broken, but it is also possible that line 9 is just the last line of the file as well, in which case you want to look for things like a missing close tag (e.g. no `</snippet>` tag) or something like extra characters somewhere after the `</snippet>` tag.

If you can't spot the location of the error, I would suggest pasting your snippet code into something like https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ to see if it can tell you what's wrong.